# Single Table inheritance with CRUD and forms in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, crud, sti

I'm a bit confused about STI in rails.

My situation:
I have a `Contact` model that has `description` and `data` string fields, to store some contact like phone, fax, email, etc.

Now when I have some specific contact type like phone number of email address I want to walidate the data format in different way and I want to make some different formating on output.

I decided to use STI as all the models have the same data with just different behaviour. And I have some questions regarding forms and CRUD operations as I don't want to go against Rails conventions.

1. How do I make a dropdown list in form with model type? Should I hardcode it or is there some more automated way?
2. How do I create a record? Should I use `switch` statement and according to received type create new model of according instance?
3. How should I update it if I'm going to change the model type? Cast the object to new class? Or create a new object and destroy the previous one?

I'll be very thankfull for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, should do a hardcore as there no default store for your STI models.
2. Generally, yes. But With Rails you could just use `camelize.constantize` to get class from string. Another way is just use parent model, and set `type` field manually. As with `STI` all records are in the same table and then all are of the parent class.
3. If you wish to update, just update `type` field. Then you could re-query to force Rails to get new object of different type.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But will the validation work for a specific model if I'll just set a type field?

Comment: @Uko yes, if you do `@model = type.camelize.contantize.new(params[:model])`

Comment: Wow, that's really nice. One more thing. How should I handle the update? Should I do something like `@model.becomes(type.camelize.contantize)` and then `@model.update_attributes(params[:model])` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a model like this :

```
Type < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts
end
```

You could use this command `rails g model Type name:string`, add a `type_id` column in your contact and migrate the database.

end change your contact's model like this :

```
Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :type
end
```

Now, in your form, you could use this :

```
select("type", "type_id", Type.all.collect {|t| [ t.name, t.id ] }, { :include_blank => true })
```

It should resolve your problem.

Now you can do something like this :

```
@emails = Type.find_by_name('email').contacts
```

Or use scopes.

Comment: Thank you for this sujjestion, I've thought about this option, but I think that STI is a better design strategy, as I have exactly the same data and just need different validations and formating, etc. So if I use STI validation vill be done depending on the model tope by itself, and in your solution I'll need to use some pre-validation callbacks with `switch` statements